# How many points does it take to fill the reputation bar?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So, I keep getting "+3 Paragon" or "+4 Renegade", but how many points does it take to fill up the bar completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum reputation is 1050, with thresholds at 210, 420, 630, 840. Numbers from `coalesced.bin`.

Comment: Those numbers seem high if I gain ~1-7 reputation every time. Is my reputation gains x10 or something?

Comment: There are easily ~300 dialogue choices and interactions in the game and plenty give 5 rep or more. 1050 isn't hard to get to at all.